# Are sins and bad deeds the same or different?

Tags: sin, terminology, deeds

Are sins and bad deeds the same or different?

I wonder if they are or not, because on the day of judgement, God will weigh up our good and bad deeds, but are bad deeds the same as sins?

Comment: I guess it depends on how you define them and what original terms in Arabic you see them as equivalent to. If you are thinking about _dhanb_ and _sayyiah_ respectively, you can look at how each term is used in the Qur'an. They do appear to be very similar.

Comment: A sin is like doing something against the rules, like its a sin killing someone innocent.  bad deed is more like you push someone because you were angry, you've hurt someone it's a bad deed but not a sin.

Answer (score 1):

No one (including the Prophet PBUH) will enter heaven by their deeds, but rather the mercy of Allah, as stated in the following hadith:

> لا يدخل أحد الجنة بعمله ، قالوا ولا أنت يا رسول الله ؟؟ قال : ولا أنا إلا أن يتداركني الله برحمته

That said, you try your best to do good deeds so Allah can have mercy on you. There are big sins and small sins. Small sins are easily forgiven by doing many good deeds like praying, attending the Masjid, caring for the poor/elderly, etc.. The big sins you should always ask Allah for forgiveness and attempt your hardest to not do them again.

Lastly, remember that doing the best of good deeds with bad attitude or behavior will not help much as the prophet PBUH said:

> إنما بعثت لأتمم مكارم الأخلاق
>
> The only reason I was sent to complete the moral compass

Answer (score 0):

Sin is  the wrong think which you do it and it is between you and God and God can forgive you for all sins, while bad deed is the wrong think which you do against others (human, animal, plants,...) and God will not forgive you unless you do a good deed

Answer (score -1):

You should pay attention to this matter that generally we can call the sins as bad deeds. But it can be surveyed from another angle as well. I mean all the sins can be divided into three main groups. The first main group of sins is called big or major sins which Allah will torment for them. Another group of bad deeds or sins are called minor sins which Allah will torture in some condition(s). Finally we can call the last group as Makruh deeds, that perhaps we can call them as the deeds which are relatively bad. so Allah will not torment for doing them, but it is better ti ignore doing them.

Comment: " Allah will not torment for doing them" ...What is the gaurantee that Allah will or will not torment for makruh deeds...?